# AWS server crashes. Can stolen time cause this?

Tags: virtual-machine, crash, amazon-web-services, docker

At work, we have two environments that are profiled with new relic. We deploy the same docker containers to both dev and production. Whats interesting is that while dev is not having issues, the production site keeps going down.

The difference between the two environments is that dev does not have stolen time on its aws servers, while production does. We see a spike in stolen cpu time right before the node.js server crashes.

From what I've read, the process should just wait, but are there scenarios where this stolen time will actually crash the server?

Comment: This will probably find a more knowledgeable user group and better answers over in WebApps.

Comment: Also, reading the descriptions of the tags are a handy way to see if a topic belongs elsewhere. For instance: amazon-web-services informs us these questions are off-topic SuperUser.

Comment: Why would you have an amazon-web-services tag in superuser if it's off topic?

Comment: That's a good question. I believe it is because we technically allow people to create their own tags, and then we clean them up, correct them, if they become common we standardize them, etc. Because AWS is a real thing, that tag has been standardized and we have added the detail that it is an off-topic topic. Additionally, some questions that are related to AWS ARE on-topic, if the AWS part is tangential but of less importance. As yours is about a function of AWS, it would be better answered over in WebApps.

Comment: Don't bother asking the question again over there. We'll get enough votes here from our high-level users and just move it over automatically.

Comment: Ok sounds like a plan

Comment: @music2myear, see this recent Meta post from a Web Apps moderator: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/11991/where-do-ec2-and-aws-questions-truly-belong.  It looks like they now want us to handle this kind of question here, and view Web Apps as focusing on web-based end-user applications, excluding hosting services.

Comment: Ah. So we should change the tag wiki.

Comment: Reading through that answer I'm thinking we could either take a wack at this here. Leave it for a few days and see if someone with that knowledge can give a good answer, or send it to ServerFault as the question pertains to the AWS services themselves.

Comment: What is "stolen time"?

Comment: Stolen time is a generic term used to describe the virtual cpu waiting on the hardware cpu for processing. If the virtual cpu waits .5 seconds before having access to hardware, the stolen time is .5 seconds.

Comment: I would be looking at service and server logs here. Is your instance sized correctly? Using an instance too small for your needs can apparently increase stolen time.